# headers of multirow multicolum large table

Tags: tables

How do I create these headers:

[image: OF]

MY code:

```
   \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry} 
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{siunitx}
  \usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  \newcommand\tc[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{table}[ht!]
 \footnotesize
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{9}{d{2.5}} }
  \toprule
   Variables & \mc{AGR\&FISH} & \mc{CONST} & \mc{ENRG} 
      & \mc{MANF} & \mc{MIN} & \mc{TRSM} & \mc{TRANS}& \mc{TRADE}& \mc{HH}\\
\midrule
  Constant  & 4.119\tc{***} &  2.372\tc{***} & 4.706\tc{***} & 2.668\tc{***} & 2.746\tc{***} & 
      3.410\tc{***} & 3.472\tc{***}& 3.470\tc{***}& 3.465\tc{***}\\
      & (1.58)&  (6.07)&  (4.27)&  (5.17)&  (5.07) \\   
\addlinespace
      NPL($-1$) & 0.520\tc{***} &  \\
      & (18.16)     &  \\  
\addlinespace
 \emph{Specialization}  \\
 Log (Loans-to-Assets) & 0.505\tc{***}\\ 
                  & (1.422)    \\  
\addlinespace
\emph{Credit Quality} \\
 Log (Loan loss provi-       & 0.361\tc{***}  & \\
      \quad sions to total loans) & (11.47)         & \\  
  \addlinespace
     Log (Diversification) & -0.022 & \\
                  & (-0.24)& \\  
   \addlinespace
   \emph{Profitability}    & \\
    Log (Return on Assets)  & -0.091^\tc{***} & \\   
                    & (-2.26)         & \\
    \addlinespace
   GDP \hfill Mov(2) & -0.039\tc{**} & -0.028\tc{**} & -0.109\tc{***}\\
              & (2.75)         & (-2.31)        & (-3.51) \\ 
   \addlinespace
       \hfill Mov(3) & & & & -0.061\tc{***}  & & -0.021\tc{**}  & \\
             & & & & (-4.60)          & & (-1.03)         & \\
    \addlinespace
    \hfill Mov(4) & & & & & -0.044\tc{**} & & -0.045\tc{***}\\
             & & & & & (1.65)         & & (-3.42)\\
 \addlinespace
   Log (Inflation)       & -0.0338\tc{***} & \\
                  & (-0.406)         & \\  
\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which headers are you referring to specifically? "industry"  and "services" or something else? Please clarify. Please also make your code compilable. Currently the `d` column type as well as the `\mc` command are undefined.

Comment: Yes the industry and services headers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to modifying the header material to meet your formatting requirements, I had to add a number of instructions and modify the `\tc` macro in order to get your code to compile.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{siunitx} % not needed for this MWE
%\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption} % not needed for this MWE
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\tc[1]{^{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}} % modified def.
%% new/missing instructions:
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}} 
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
      l *{8}{d{2.5}} d{1.6} }
  \toprule
  Variables 
       & \mc{AGR\&FISH} 
       & \multicolumn{4}{c}{INDUSTRY} 
       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{SERVICES}
       & \mc{HH} \\
  \cmidrule{3-6} \cmidrule{7-9}
     && \mc{CONSTR} & \mc{ENRG} & \mc{MANF} & \mc{MIN} &
        \mc{TRSM} & \mc{TRANS} & \mc{TRADE} \\
  \midrule
  Constant  & 4.119\tc{***} & 2.372\tc{***} & 4.706\tc{***} 
            & 2.668\tc{***} & 2.746\tc{***} & 3.410\tc{***} 
            & 3.472\tc{***} & 3.470\tc{***} & 3.465\tc{***} \\
            & (1.58)&  (6.07)&  (4.27)&  (5.17)&  (5.07) \\   
  \addlinespace
  NPL($-1$) & 0.520\tc{***} &  \\
            & (18.16)       &  \\  
  \addlinespace
  \emph{Specialization} \\
  Log(Loans-to-Assets) & 0.505\tc{***}\\ 
                        & (1.422)    \\  
  \addlinespace
  \emph{Credit Quality} \\
  Log(Loan loss provi-       & 0.361\tc{***}  & \\
  \quad sions to total loans) & (11.47)         & \\  
  \addlinespace
  Log(Diversification)  & -0.022 & \\
                         & (-0.24)& \\  
  \addlinespace
  \emph{Profitability} \\
  Log(Return on Assets) & -0.091\tc{***} & \\   
                         & (-2.26)         & \\
  \addlinespace
  GDP\quad Mov(2) & -0.039\tc{**} & -0.028\tc{**} & -0.109\tc{***}\\
                    & (2.75)         & (-2.31)        & (-3.51) \\ 
  \addlinespace
  \phantom{GDP}\quad Mov(3) & & & & -0.061\tc{***}  & & -0.021\tc{**}  & \\
                            & & & & (-4.60)          & & (-1.03)       & \\
  \addlinespace
  \phantom{GDP}\quad Mov(4) & & & & & -0.044\tc{**} & & -0.045\tc{***}\\
                            & & & & & (1.65)        & & (-3.42)\\
  \addlinespace
  Log(Inflation)    & -0.0338\tc{***} & \\
                    & (-0.406)        & \\  
  %%%\addlinespace % not needed
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Mico, Thank you for sharing your expertise, I really appreciate it!